# Recover the noisy POVMs of Bell basis measurement

Tags: measurement, bell-basis, povm, depolarizing-channel

Considering Bell basis measurement, we have that the ideal POVMs are four Bell states, which can be obtained by reversing the following quantum circuits. Now, we add depolarizing errors to CX gate and H gate. This becomes a noisy Bell basis measurement. So can we derive the $\textbf{noisy}$ POVMs given the the parameters of the depolarizing errors?

[image: Bell basis measurement: from wiki]

Answer (score 1):

To set up the problem and the notations, let's first analyze why your figure corresponds to projective measurement on four Bell basis. Let's use $U_C$ stands for CNOT gate and $H$ stands for Hadamard gate. Suppose we input a quantum state $\rho$ and let it pass through a CNOT gate followed by a Hadamard gate before a final projective measurement on the computational basis<sup>1</sup> $|b\rangle$. To see why this is the measurement you mentioned, we only need to notice the probability to get result $b$ is
$$
\langle b|HU_C\rho U_{C}^{\dagger}H^{\dagger}|b\rangle =\langle \psi _{\mathrm{Bell}}|\rho |\psi _{\mathrm{Bell}}\rangle  \tag 1.
$$

Now we are ready for your problem. I'll give a simple but general example for you while leaving details to be determined yourself. Let's consider a noise channel $\mathcal{E}$ before the Hadamard gate is acted. Then, the probability to get the result $b$ now becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\langle b|H\mathcal{E} \left( U_C\rho U_{C}^{\dagger} \right) H^{\dagger}|b\rangle &=\mathrm{tr}\left[ H\mathcal{E} \left( U_C\rho U_{C}^{\dagger} \right) H^{\dagger}|b\rangle \langle b| \right] 
\\
&=\mathrm{tr}\left[ \mathcal{E} \left( U_C\rho U_{C}^{\dagger} \right) H^{\dagger}|b\rangle \langle b|H \right] 
\\
&=\mathrm{tr}\left[ U_C\rho U_{C}^{\dagger}\mathcal{E} ^*\left( H^{\dagger}|b\rangle \langle b|H \right) \right] 
\\
&=\mathrm{tr}\left[ \rho U_{C}^{\dagger}\mathcal{E} ^*\left( H^{\dagger}|b\rangle \langle b|H \right) U_C \right] 
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$
where the $\mathcal{E} ^*$ stands for the adjoint map<sup>2</sup> of $\mathcal{E}$ which has Kraus operator form $\mathcal{E} ^*\left( \cdot \right) =\sum_i{K_{i}^{\dagger}\cdot K_i}$ if $\mathcal{E} $ has Kraus operator form $\mathcal{E} \left( \cdot \right) =\sum_i{K_i\cdot K_{i}^{\dagger}}$. Notice that eq(2) is your answer by thinking $U_{C}^{\dagger}\mathcal{E} ^*\left( H^{\dagger}|b\rangle \langle b|H \right) U_C$ as one element of POVM.

<sub>1. For example, in your two qubits case, the computational basis is $|00\rangle ,|01\rangle ,|10\rangle ,|11\rangle$.</sub>

<sub>2. You can find this definition in John Watrous's book: The theory of Quantum Information, section Mathematical Preliminaries.</sub>